# If I ask a tech support question and the question dies, can I ask an updated question?

Tags: discussion, comments

I asked a question on Super User and some answers didn't answer my question and there were comments asking for further information. I replied to the comments, and I also replied to the answers that didn't answer my question. However, no one responded. Am I allowed to ask a similar question now, but with updated information now that I've done more research? Or would that qualify as a duplicate or violet the rules in some other way?

Comment: As the duplicate states, no. The better way is to continue to edit your original question with newer information and research as you find it. This will also bump your question to the top of the list, hopefully getting you more attention.